# Month directly from YYYYMM

Tags: excel

I have many values formatted as `YYYYMM`:

```
201007
201008
```

How can I directly extract the month from these values?

```
201007    jul
201008    aug
```

I have tried numerous ways found online, a.o.

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(A2;2)*29;"mmm")
```

But I have been unsuccesful.

Answer (score 3):

So, with `201007` in `A2`, what about doing

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A2; 4); RIGHT(A2; 2); 1); "mmm")
```

which returns `Jul`

---

Actually, you first have to convert your input into a native excel date-object by doing [`DATE`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349)`(LEFT(A2; 4); RIGHT(A2; 2); 1)`.

Finaly, using the function [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) over it will natively extract the wanted information, i.e. the month name.

---

*As explained by Gary's Student, my solution is an heavy-handed approach if your dates are genuine*.

Comment: this would be useful if `201007` were a string and not a formatted Excel date

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Cell `A2` is of the type `TEXT`, and I'm using `=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A2;4);RIGHT(A2;2);1);"mmm")` but it only returns `00`?

Comment: @Pr0no It looks like you have a space character before your date. What does `LEFT(A2;4)` return ? Idem for `RIGHT(A2;2)`, what does it return? You can use the function `TRIM` on `A2` to remove unwanted framing spaces.

Answer (score 3):

With values in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmm")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

*(this assumes that the values in column **A** are genuine Excel dates.)*